# Fourier analysis convergence argument help

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $g \in L^{1}([0,1])$ and define:

$\hat{g}(n)=\int g(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to show that if $g\in L^{1}([0,1])$

and $\{\hat{g}(n)\}\in\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$

then $S_{N}g(x)=\underset{|n|\leq N}{\sum}\hat{g}(n)e^{2\pi inx}$ converges on $[0,1]$.

Attempt so far:

We know that $\sum|\hat{g_n}|<\infty$.

Being absolutely convergent, can define $g_0:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow C$ as:
$$g_0(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}\hat{g}e^{2\pi inx}=lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}S_Ng(x)$$
We can observe that the limit is uniform in $x$ because:
$|g_0(x)-S_Ng| \leq \sum_{|n|>N}\hat{g}(n)$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Which leads to: $$\lVert g_0 - S_N g \rVert_{\infty}\leq \sum_{|n|>N}\hat{g}(n)\rightarrow 0$$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$

So,

$$lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \lVert \frac{S_0g + S_1g+...+S_{N-1}g}{N} \rVert_{\infty}=0$$

Is the above attempt legitimate? Any clarifications and all criticisms are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have proved  the Fourier series converges uniformly to some function $g_0$. To show that $g=g_0$ a.e. it is enough to show that $\hat g(n)=\hat{g_0}(n)$ for all $n$. For this write down  the definition of $\hat{g_0}(n)$ and interchange the integral and the limit (which is permissible by uniform convergence).